# Use of units in Nakayama's Lemma's proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Given the Nakayama's Lemma: 
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. If $I\subseteq J(A)$, the Jacobson radical, such that $IM=M$, then $M=0$.

I've looked up some proofs and understood them all except this one here:

Proof:
Suppose $IM=M$. Taking $\phi; M \rightarrow M$ to be the identity map .
Because of the determinant trick we obtain an element $x\in A$ such that $x-1 \in I$  and $xM=0$.
$I$ is cointained in the Jacobson radical. Recall that $x\in J(A)$ iff $1-xy$  is a unit for all $y\in A$.
Taking $y$ to be equal $1$ we get

(*):     $ 1-(1-x)$ is a unit in $A$ which implies $x$ is a unit in A and $xM=0$ which finally implies $M=0$.

I don't understand the (*) part. Why can we assume that a sum of units is a unit here? That is why can we conclude that $x$ is unit? The rest of the proof is fine with me. Thank you for your help

Comment: The claim is not "sum of units is a unit."  The claim is just the previous line that $1-j$ is a unit if $j\in J(A)$, and in particular $j=1-x\in I\subseteq J(A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is just repeated use of the symbol $x$. Rewrite the proof as follows:

> Suppose $IM=M$. Taking $\phi; M \rightarrow M$ to be the identity map
>   . Because of the determinant trick we obtain an element $x\in A$ such
>   that $x-1 \in I$  and $xM=0$. $I$ is cointained in the Jacobson
>   radical. **Recall that $z\in J(A)$ iff $1-yz$  is a unit for all $y\in
>  A$.** **Taking $y$ to be equal $-1$ and $z$ to be $x-1$** we get  $ 1-(-1)
> \cdot(x-1)$
>   is a unit in $A$ which implies $x$ is a unit in A and $xM=0$ which
>   finally implies $M=0$.

Note that $x-1 \in I \subseteq J(A)$, so $1- (-1) \cdot (x-1)=x$ must be a unit.